# use GSON in jsp page

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to serialize an object in JSON using a JSP like format using the following code:

```
ArrayList<AccountBean> al = new ArrayList<AccountBean>();
al = vc.getAccountName();
int i=0;
out.print("[");
while(i<al.size()){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    out.print("{ID"+al.get(i).getAno()+":name"+al.get(i).getAccount_name()+"},");
    i++;
}
out.print("]");
```

I'm getting a output like this:

```
[{ID1:nameEquity Share Capitals},{ID2:nameCalls In Arear},]
```

but my requirement is something like this:

```
[{"ID1":"nameEquity Share Capitals"},{"ID2":"nameCalls In Arear"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
out.print('{"ID'+al.get(i).getAno()+'":"name'+al.get(i).getAccount_name()+'"},')
```

use `'` to open/close the string, and `"` to wrap your json keys/values.

Otherwise you can do like this

```
out.print("{\"ID"+al.get(i).getAno()+"\":\"name"+al.get(i).getAccount_name()+"\"},")
```

escaping the quotes with `\"`

---

Anyway, have you tried this?

```
String json = gson.toJson(al)
```

Have a look here for more info: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: There really isn't a cleaner way to get this kind of serialization from Gson (it's a really non standard need to go from an array of Beans to a series to keys)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is using a *custom serializer* and I can edit this answer posting one if you want to go deeper.

However, since you are quite new to JSON and Gson I would answer with this simple code that you can paste&try in you IDE. I just "convert" you bean into a map, and the use Gson to serialize.

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Q20323412 {


   public static class AccountBean{
      Integer _id;
      String _name;

      public String getAccount_name(){
         return _name;
      }

      public Integer getAno(){
         // what a weird name, in italian for this method..
         return _id;

      }

      public AccountBean(Integer id, String name){
         _id = id;
         _name = name;
      }
   }

   /**
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<AccountBean> al = new ArrayList<AccountBean>();
      al.add(new AccountBean(1, "Equity Share Capitals"));
      al.add(new AccountBean(2, "Calls In Arear"));

      ArrayList<Map> al2 = new ArrayList<>();
      for(AccountBean account : al){
         HashMap hm = new HashMap();
         hm.put("ID"+ account.getAno(), "name"+account.getAccount_name());
         al2.add(hm);
      }

      Gson g = new Gson();
      System.out.println(g.toJson(al2));

   }

}
```

Since you did not post your bean, I invented one that has features similar to your's.